# How to get lapsed time over 2 days python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

hoping you can help me solve this one.
I am working on a project which involves tracking lapse time between when an order is placed and when it's delivered. The date formats of the file I'm working with is as follows:
"Calendar Day :hour:minute:second"

That said, I was able to create datetime64[ns] objects for the attributes using the following code:

```
df["Customer placed order datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Customer placed order datetime"], format='%d %H:%M:%S')
data["Delivered to consumer datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Delivered to consumer datetime"], format='%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am then taking the difference of when an order is delivered - when it was placed to get the total time lapse

```
data["lapse"] = data["Delivered to consumer datetime"] - data["Customer placed order datetime"]
```

This works great for orders delivered the same day, however I am running into a problem with orders placed late at night and delivered the next day. Please see example below:

Customer placed order | datetime Delivered to consumer datetime  | lapse

1900-01-31 23:59:46     |       1900-01-01 01:49:07     |   31 days +01:49:21

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: There are literally 31 days between these two dates.

Answer (score 0):

The example provided doesn't reflect the problem you are trying to solve. The dates in the example are a month apart from one another. Try to recreate the error using a valid example and see if the issue still persists

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).